# How can I troubleshoot this SSL certificate error?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, ssl-certificate

First off, I'm not a server admin, I'm by no means an expert.

So, there are two servers, one is used for email relaying and the other runs a website. The website will use .NET to send a message through SMTP with UseSSL flagged. However it fails due to the error

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

So I enabled tracing and the log outputted this message

> System.Net Information: 0 : [4656]
>   SecureChannel#22800124 - Remote
>   certificate has errors: System.Net
>   Information: 0 : [4656]
>   SecureChannel#22800124 -  A
>   certificate chain processed, but
>   terminated in a root certificate which
>   is not trusted by the trust provider.
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [4656]
>   SecureChannel#22800124 - Remote
>   certificate was verified as invalid by
>   the user.
>
> System.Net Error: 0 : [4656]
>   Exception in the
>   SmtpClient#34708722::Send - The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to
>   the validation procedure.

So we double checked, and the certificate on the email server was expired. Someone created a new self signed certificate on the email server, and it was imported to the trusted root certificate authority on the web server. That didn't fix the error.

Any ideas on what else I can check? Or was that not how you set a certificate to be trusted?

Also, when not using SSL the application works fine, and nothing should be wrong with the application itself, as it use to work up until a little while ago (when the old certificate expired) and it can run fine on other servers.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need to restart IIS to reload the certificate keystore.

You can also check the remote certificate with:

```
openssl s_client -connect SMTPserver:port|openssl x509 -text
```

You can find openssl at http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Comment: +1, Thanks for the answer. I'm unable to test this until tomorrow, I will let you know then.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the best online tutorial that I have found on using the **s_client** feature of the **openssl** toolchain.

Check out [The OpenSSL Command-Line Howto](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/) by Paul Heinlein.

All of Paul's guides are great, but this one stands out for giving you a great walk through of all the tools that you can use to manage and/or troubleshoot your SSL certificate issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to make sure that the server is giving out the correct intermediate certificates and doesn't have any other errors.